# Using Product CRUD setter methods in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, setter

In the code bellow, I can't set some product category and product tags:

The code is located in my functions.php file:

```
<?php

$product = new WC_Product;
$product->set_name("product");
$product->set_regular_price('150');
$set_cat = $product->set_category_ids( array(17) );
$set_tag = $product->set_tag_ids( [18, 19] );
$product->save();

var_dump($set_cat);//NULL
var_dump($set_tag);//NULL
```

The product is created with the correct `name` and `price`. But I get nothing for the product category and product tags:

```
terms:
[terms table][1]

term_taxonomy:
[term_taxonomy table][2]
```

> **Edit:** I have moved this code in `index.php` file and It works.

Comment: Could you add a bit more clarification to this question, what exactly are you trying to do and what aspect of it is not working, have you tried anything else to address the issue?

Comment: You should have a look to the answer, as there is still something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since Woocommerce 3, [new CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) are available.

**But you can not use a setter method in a variables** like in this extract of your code:

```
$set_cat = $product->set_category_ids( array(17) );
$set_tag = $product->set_tag_ids( [18, 19] );
```

Instead, **it should be only:**

```
$product->set_category_ids( array(17) );
$product->set_tag_ids( [18, 19] );

$product->save();
```

Then just after you will **use getter methods** to read the saved data and display it:

```
$get_cats = $product->get_category_ids();
$get_tags = $product->get_tag_ids();

var_dump($get_cats); // NOW OK
var_dump($get_tags); // NOW OK
```

For `function.php` file you should embed you code in a function like:

```
function my_custom_function_code(){
    // Get a new empty WC_Product instance object
    $product = new WC_Product; 

    # Setter methods (set the data)

    $product->set_name("product");
    $product->set_regular_price('150');

    $product->set_category_ids( array(17) );
    $product->set_tag_ids( [18, 19] );

    # Save the data

    $product->save(); // Always at the end to save the new data

    # Getter methods (Read the data)

    $get_cats = $product->get_category_ids();
    $get_tags = $product->get_tag_ids();

    # Display some raw data

    var_dump($get_cats); // NOW OK
    var_dump($get_tags); // NOW OK
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere else *(like in your index.php file)* simply with:

```
my_custom_function_code();
```